# Access nested data without appending in d3.js

Tags: arrays, d3.js, nested, selection, hierarchical-data

I'm having a really hard time understanding how nested selections work. I looked for similar questions but none consider a case in which you **access nested data just to set an attribute**, without appending anything.

I want to visualize the **number of meteorite landings by year in a horizontal bar chart**:
one rect for each year, with width equal to the number of meteorites fallen that year.

This is the data format (csv):

```
name,id,nametype,recclass,rectype,mass,fall,year,reclat,reclong,GeoLocation
Renazzo,22586,Valid,CR2,Stony,1000,Fell,1824,44.76667,11.28333,"(44.76667, 11.28333)"
Tounkin,24037,Valid,OC,Stony,2000,Fell,1824,51.73333,102.53333,"(51.73333, 102.53333)"
Zebrak,30397,Valid,H5,Stony,2000,Fell,1824,49.88333,13.91667,"(49.88333, 13.91667)"
```

In this case, for example, I should get a single bar with length 3.

First thing, I group the data by year through nesting:

```
var dataByYear = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
        return d.year;
    })
    .entries(data);
```

I don't use rollup because I need to preserve the values and access them later (I'll need name, nametype, year and mass).

The resulting array looks like this:

[image]

Then I draw the rects:

```
barSvg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataByYear).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 23;
    })
    .attr("height", 10)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d, i) {
        return d;
    }).enter()
    .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.year.lenght;
    });
```

The console doesn't display error messages, and all rectangles are drawn but their height attribute doesn't show up.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using `data()` and `enter()` again in the "enter" selection makes no sense. Get rid of that.

In your enter selection, each datum has a `key` property and a `values` property. The way to get the number of fallen meteorites in that year is simply using `values.length`.

Here is a demo with your data (which will render a single rectangle):

```js
var csv = `name,id,nametype,recclass,rectype,mass,fall,year,reclat,reclong,GeoLocation
Renazzo,22586,Valid,CR2,Stony,1000,Fell,1824,44.76667,11.28333,"(44.76667, 11.28333)"
Tounkin,24037,Valid,OC,Stony,2000,Fell,1824,51.73333,102.53333,"(51.73333, 102.53333)"
Zebrak,30397,Valid,H5,Stony,2000,Fell,1824,49.88333,13.91667,"(49.88333, 13.91667)"`;

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);
var dataByYear = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  })
  .entries(data);

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataByYear)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 23;
  })
  .attr("height", 10)
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.values.length * 10
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for such a fast reply! I updated my code, but height still returns NaN... I tried 'd[values].lenght' too, but in the console it says "values is not defined".

Comment: Are you using D3 v3? In that case it is `value` instead.

Comment: It's v4, and even `value` won't work. Console says: ''Unnamed value NaN during interpretation of the width attribute 257''. Could it be an error in the data?

Comment: By the way, can I ask why you used `null` in `selectAll`? I'm sorry if I make stupid questions, I'm really new to d3

Comment: I also tried to `console.log(d.values)` inside a `dataByYear.forEach`. I also tried `values.mass` instead of `values.year`. I still get the same error in the console. 257 is the number of occurencies (as many as the different years). Is it a corrupted entry?

Comment: Well, as you can see, my snippet is running OK with `values`. So, I advise you to create a jsfiddle/plunker/whatever, so I can better see what's happening.

Comment: If I've done everything correctly, it shoul be here https://jsfiddle.net/Leonie/7yrnc00t/

Comment: No, you didn't do it correctly, because the path to the CSV is wrong. But the code **is** working, I just changed the `d3.csv` for the variable: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/5Lu9ja11/.

Comment: I tried adding the complete data to your fiddle and it works. When I copy and paste the same code on atom and access it through firefox, the page doesn't even have any svg tag. Maybe I'm doing something stupid because I'm tired. I'll try again tomorrow. Anyway, thank you for your time, you've been very kind!

Comment: No worries. If you still have a trouble tomorrow, please post another question, with all the details. I believe you have a *different* problem somewhere else.

Comment: Solved: it was the position of the script inside the html. It loaded before the elements did. I wonder why I didn't get this problem before, then. But still, as long as it works...